# Replacing special characters with php script

Tags: php

I want to replace the special characters with html codes. Here is the code, but it return with: **0**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Coding...</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function coding($string)
    {
        $character = array(" ","!",'"',"#","$","%","&","'","(",")","*","+",",","-",".","/","<","=",">","á","Á","é","É","í","Í","ó","Ó","ö","Ö","ő","Ő","ú","Ú","ü","Ü","ű","Ű","@","[","\\","]","^","_","{","|","}","~");
        $code = array("&#32;","&#33;","&#34;","&#35;","&#36;","&#37;","&#38;","&#39;","&#40;","&#41;","&#42;","&#43;","&#44;","&#45;","&#46;","&#47;","&#60;","&#61;","&#62;","&#225;","&#193;","&#233;","&#201;","&#237;","&#205;","&#243;","&#211;","&#246;","&#214;","&#337;","&#336;","&#250;","&#218;","&#252;","&#220;","&#369;","&#368;","&#64;","&#91;","&#92;","&#93;","&#94;","&#95;","&#123;","&#124;","&#125;","&#126;");
        $length=count($character);
        $string1=array();
        for ($a = 0; $a<strlen($string); $a++)
            {
                $found=false;
                $sz='';
                $char=$string[$a];
                for ($i = 0; $i<=count($character); $i++) 
                    {
                        if ($character[$i]==$string[$a])
                            {
                                $sz= $code[$i];
                                $i=count($character);
                                $found=true;
                            };
                    };
                if (!$found) {$sz= $char;}
                //echo $sz;
                $string1[]=$sz; 
            };
        for ($a = 0; $a<=count($string1); $a++)
            {
                $string2=$string2+$string1[$a];
            };
        return $string2;
    };
$string = "áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖőŐúÚüÜűŰ !";
echo coding($string)."\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

*coding($string)* steps:

- create two arrays
- in the *for* cycle it one by one check the characters, if it special add html code to *$string1* array else add the original character
- create string ($string2) from the array

Please help me, where did I go wrong?

Comment: There are standard functions to encode / decode special characters. And, yes, you could encode them also following your approach. I've added an answer showing both.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 standard functions available in PHP:

- *htmlspecialchars()*: transform normal into special characters.
- *htmlspecialchars_decode()*: transfrom special into normal characters.

Based on your code you find a function that transfers from normal to special (encoded) characters. This is probably what you tried to do.

```
    <?php
    // Standard PHP functions
    $string = '&#32;&#33;&#34;&#35;&#36;&#37;&#38;&#39;&#40;&#41;&#42;&#43;&#44;&#45;&#46;&#47;&#60;&#61;&#62;&#225;&#193;&#233;&#201;&#237;&#205;&#243;&#211;&#246;&#214;&#337;&#336;&#250;&#218;&#252;&#220;&#369;&#368;&#64;&#91;&#92;&#93;&#94;&#95;&#123;&#124;&#125;&#126;';
    echo 'htmlspecialchars_decode(): ' . htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES) . '<br />';
    $string = "'!\"#$%&'()*+,-./<=>áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖoOúÚüÜuU@[\]^_{|}~";
    echo 'htmlspecialchars(): ' . htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT)) . '<br />';

    // Based on your code
    function coding($string)
    {
        $character = array(" ","!",'"',"#","$","%","&","'","(",")","*","+",",","-",".","/","<","=",">","á","Á","é","É","í","Í","ó","Ó","ö","Ö","o","O","ú","Ú","ü","Ü","u","U","@","[","\\","]","^","_","{","|","}","~");
        $code = array("&#32;","&#33;","&#34;","&#35;","&#36;","&#37;","&#38;","&#39;","&#40;","&#41;","&#42;","&#43;","&#44;","&#45;","&#46;","&#47;","&#60;","&#61;","&#62;","&#225;","&#193;","&#233;","&#201;","&#237;","&#205;","&#243;","&#211;","&#246;","&#214;","&#337;","&#336;","&#250;","&#218;","&#252;","&#220;","&#369;","&#368;","&#64;","&#91;","&#92;","&#93;","&#94;","&#95;","&#123;","&#124;","&#125;","&#126;");
        $result = '';
        $maxind = strlen($string);
        for($i=0; $i<$maxind; $i++) {
            $index = array_search($string[$i], $character);
            if ($index!==false) $result .= $code[$index];
        }
        return $result;
    };
    $string = "'!\"#$%&'()*+,-./<=>áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖoOúÚüÜuU@[\]^_{|}~";
    echo 'coding(): ' . htmlentities(coding($string)) . '<br />'; // htmlentities() to show "as is" in a html page
```

...gives this:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(): !"#$%&'()*+,-./<=>áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖőŐúÚüÜűŰ@[\]^_{|}~
htmlspecialchars(): '!&quot;#$%&amp;'()*+,-./&lt;=&gt;áÁéÉíÍóÓöÖoOúÚüÜuU@[\]^_{|}~
coding(): &#39;&#33;&#34;&#35;&#36;&#37;&#38;&#39;&#40;&#41;&#42;&#43;&#44;&#45;&#46;&#47;&#60;&#61;&#62;&#225;&#193;&#233;&#201;&#237;&#205;&#243;&#211;&#246;&#214;&#337;&#336;&#250;&#218;&#252;&#220;&#369;&#368;&#64;&#91;&#92;&#93;&#94;&#95;&#123;&#124;&#125;&#126;
```

Comment: If I coding the string it gives this:

    '!"#$%&'()*+,-./<=>őŐűŰ@[\]^_{|}~

Comment: Look at the source code of the page. You will see the &#99; encoded characters. They, of corse are shown like you show. The browser interpretes the characters.

Answer (score 0):

If do not talk about real problem:

1) You not initialize `$string2`variable

2) Invalid condition in loops:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<=count($character); $i++)
```

**must be**

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($character); $i++)
```

**and**

```
for ($a = 0; $a<=count($string1); $a++)
```

**must be**

```
for ($a = 0; $a<count($string1); $a++)
```

3) You do not concatenate the strings, you are convert them into numbers and summing up their:

```
$string2=$string2+$string1[$a];
```

**must be**

```
$string2 = $string2 . $string1[$a];
```